# Initialize table column based on button click

Tags: java, javafx

I am fairly new in JavaFX. I have a table with multiple columns and two buttons (`btnBuilding` , `btnBSearch`) outside the table. In the table, I have a column `colAction` where I want to have some buttons based on the button clicked outside the table. Suppose if I click `btnBuilding` I want to have 2 button `Save` and `Refresh` in my `colAction` column and Whenever I click `btnBSearch` I want to have 2 button `Edit` and `Add` in my `colAction` column. Inside the `initialize()` I tried like below

```
colAction.setCellFactory(col -> {
                Button SaveButton = new Button("Save");
                Button AddButton = new Button("Add");
                Button RefreshButton = new Button("Refresh");
                Button EditButton = new Button("Edit");
              HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
               if(btnBSearch.isFocused())
               hbox.getChildren().addAll(AddButton,EditButton);
               else if(btnBuilding.isFocused())
                   hbox.getChildren().addAll(SaveButton,RefreshButton);


                TableCell<ModelBrBuilding, ModelBrBuilding> cell = new TableCell<ModelBrBuilding, ModelBrBuilding>() {
                    @Override
                    //Updating with the number of row 
                    public void updateItem(ModelBrBuilding building, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(building, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(hbox);
                        }
                    }

                };

                EditButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->{               
                });

                RefreshButton.setOnAction(event->{          
                });

                SaveButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {                     
                });
                AddButton.setOnAction(event -> {                                  
                    });

                return cell ;
            });
```

But the problem is whatever button I click I am always getting `Add` and `Edit` in my action column. How can I add different button in my column based on the button (resides outside the table) I click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work this way. To begin with, you need to process the `btnBuilding` and `btnBSearch` buttons. Which of the buttons is pressed must reflect in the table you are using. For this purpose, one feature can be created propert to reflect which of the two buttons is pressed.

```
BooleanProperty showSearch = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
...
btnBuilding.setOnAction(e -> showSearch.setValue(false));
btnBSearch.setOnAction(e -> showSearch.setValue(true));
```

Then, you link the `colAction` column to the value of the property.

```
colAction.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> showSearch);
```

In this situation, you can create `CellFactory` to create the dynamic content cell

```
colAction.setCellFactory(col -> {
    return new TableCell<String, Boolean>() {
        Button SaveButton = new Button("Save");
        Button AddButton = new Button("Add");
        Button RefreshButton = new Button("Refresh");
        Button EditButton = new Button("Edit");

        HBox hboxBuilding = new HBox(5);
        HBox hboxSearch = new HBox(5);

        {
            hboxBuilding.getChildren().addAll(AddButton,EditButton);
            hboxSearch.getChildren().addAll(SaveButton,RefreshButton);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            }
            else {
                setGraphic(item ? hboxBuilding : hboxSearch);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Its now adding only `Save` and `Refresh`

Answer (score 1):

The `cellFactory` runs only once for each cell. You need to make sure the cell is updated the button outside of the table is clicked.

You could do this by creating a property that contains a factory for the `graphic`s and listen to it.

```
public interface GraphicFactory<T> {

    Node createGraphic();

    void updateGraphic(Node graphic, T item);
}
```

```
public class ReplacableGraphicTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    private final ChangeListener<GraphicFactory<T>> factoryListener = (o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == null || isEmpty()) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            Node n = newValue.createGraphic();
            newValue.updateGraphic(n, getItem());
            setGraphic(n);
        }
    };

    private final ObservableValue<GraphicFactory<T>> factory;

    private ReplacableGraphicTableCell(ObservableValue<GraphicFactory<T>> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
        factory.addListener(factoryListener);
    }

    public static <E, F> Callback<TableColumn<E, F>, TableCell<E, F>> forTableColumn(ObservableValue<GraphicFactory<F>> factory) {
        if (factory == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return column -> new ReplacableGraphicTableCell(factory);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            GraphicFactory<T> fact = factory.getValue();
            if (fact == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                Node graphic = getGraphic();
                if (graphic == null) {
                    graphic = fact.createGraphic();
                    setGraphic(graphic);
                }

                fact.updateGraphic(graphic, item);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
final ObjectProperty<GraphicFactory<Item>> graphicFactory = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
TableColumn<Item, Item> column = new TableColumn<>();
column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cd.getValue()));
column.setCellFactory(ReplacableGraphicTableCell.forTableColumn(graphicFactory));

ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
tg.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    GraphicFactory<Item> factory = null;
    if (newValue != null) {
        factory = (GraphicFactory<Item>) newValue.getUserData();
    }
    graphicFactory.set(factory);
});
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton("Add/Edit");
rb.setUserData(new GraphicFactory<Item>() {

    @Override
    public Node createGraphic() {
        Button add = new Button("Add");
        Button edit = new Button("Edit");

        HBox hbox = new HBox(add, edit);
        add.setOnAction(evt -> {
            System.out.println("Add " + hbox.getUserData());
        });
        edit.setOnAction(evt -> {
            System.out.println("Edit " + hbox.getUserData());
        });
        return hbox;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateGraphic(Node graphic, Item item) {
        graphic.setUserData(item);
    }

});
rb.setToggleGroup(tg);

RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Save/Refresh");
rb2.setUserData(new GraphicFactory<Item>() {

    @Override
    public Node createGraphic() {
        Button save = new Button("Save");
        Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");

        HBox hbox = new HBox(save, refresh);
        save.setOnAction(evt -> {
            System.out.println("Save " + hbox.getUserData());
        });
        refresh.setOnAction(evt -> {
            System.out.println("Refresh " + hbox.getUserData());
        });
        return hbox;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateGraphic(Node graphic, Item item) {
        graphic.setUserData(item);
    }

});
rb2.setToggleGroup(tg);
```